# cmake #cmakedefine and #define behave inconsistently with cmake variables such as PROJECT_BINARY_DIR that already exist

Tags: cmake

cmake #cmakedefine and #define behave inconsistently with cmake variables such as PROJECT_BINARY_DIR that already exist.

In the case of the PROJECT function definition, the PROJECT_BINARY_DIR variable will exist, and the input file of the configure_file function should also be accessible later.
Actually, the input file of configure_file cannot find the "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" variable used by #cmakedefine, but the "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" variable used by #define of the input file can be found. Do you know the reason and details? ?

mini demo:
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Tutorial
        VERSION 1.2
        )
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
configure_file(xxx.h.in xxx.h)
```

xxx.h.in

```
#cmakedefine testProjectBinDir "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
#define testProjectBinDir "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
```

output:
xxx.h

```
/* #undef testProjectBinDir */
#define testProjectBinDir "/home/a/b/build"
```

Why can't #cmakedefine get the value? The CMakeLists.txt file is a standard basic file. PROJECT defines the PROJECT_BINARY_DIR variable. This variable should be a variable owned by CMake. Why can't only #cmakedefine get the value?

My problem is that the PROJECT_BINARY_DIR variable is set by the PROJECT function. In the xxx.h.in input file, the results obtained are different depending on the use of different instructions (#cmakedefine and #define). I want to understand why? Or is it because of scope or timing of execution?

Comment: Hello, Minimal examples have been added.@Tsyvarev

Comment: `#cmakedefine` takes value of the macro from the variable of the **same name**. That is,  in your case CMake checks the variable `testProjectBinDir`. [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) correctly describes those aspects of the command.